# NSDate formatting from NSString

Tags: ios, ipad

I have data in `NSString`, I need to display it as `Oct 3, 2011`. I am having trouble in converting nsstring into `NSDate` and then again display it as `NSString`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy "];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
```

myString is 2011-10-3 00:00:00

Comment: Can you show the code where you init/set `myString`?

Comment: Also, what is the problem you are having specifically -- error message?  exception thrown?  String looks funny?

Comment: Duh, he's trying to convert the input string using the format of the desired output string.  Obviously it's not going to work.

Comment: problem I am facing is first to convert this string into NSDate and then NSDate to mediumstyle i.e, Oct 3, 2011

Answer (score 0):

First set the date formatter time zone.  If the string you're receiving is GMT/UTC, set the timezone to that.

Next set the date format to match the incoming date pattern.  Do dateFromString.

Then set the date format to match the desired output format.  Also set the output timezone, if different.  Do stringFromDate, using as input the NSDate object from the previous operation.